# Navigation view with drag indicator

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Let's say I am opening a modal from my main view and then modal is opening a subview within it. My modal does not have a drag indicator on top, so my guess that's why the subview doesn't have drag indicator on top as well.

How do I get drag indicator to show up in the subview(NavigationA view in my code below)? I am adding ".presentationDragIndicator(.visible)" but that's not helping.

***Code:***

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSheet: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Click Me").font(.title).foregroundStyle(Color.blue).onTapGesture {
                self.showSheet.toggle()
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) { SheetA() }
    }
}

struct SheetA: View {
    @State var showSubView: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Show Navigation View").foregroundStyle(Color.blue).font(.title).onTapGesture {
                    self.showSubView.toggle()
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: self.$showSubView) { NavigationA() }
            .presentationDetents([.large])
            .presentationDragIndicator(.hidden)
            .interactiveDismissDisabled()
        }
    }
}

/// This view when presented should have drag indicator or handler on the top.
struct NavigationA: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is the navigation view. \nThis view should have drag handler on top")
        }
        .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
        .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
        .interactiveDismissDisabled()
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
    }
}
```

I need drag indicator on this view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `presentationXXX` modifiers only work when they are directly attached to the view that is presented (in this case, the `NavigationStack`). They don't work otherwise, so you should remove them from `NavigationA`.

You can use a conditional expression to determine the value you should pass to `presentationDragIndicator`:

```
NavigationStack {
    VStack {
        Text("Show Navigation View").foregroundStyle(Color.blue).font(.title).onTapGesture {
            self.showSubView.toggle()
        }
    }
    .navigationDestination(isPresented: self.$showSubView) { NavigationA() }
}
// put the presentation-related modifiers on the NavigationStack
.presentationDragIndicator(showSubView ? .visible : .hidden)
.interactiveDismissDisabled()
```

Since you want `NavigationA` to have different presentation detents, you should do:

```
.presentationDetents(showSubView ? [.large, .medium] : [.large])
```

Apparently this causes the detent to suddenly change to `.medium` when you navigate. To avoid that, you can bind the selected detent to a `@State` that you control:

```
@State var detent = PresentationDetent.large
```

```
.presentationDetents(showSubView ? [.large, .medium] : [.large], selection: $detent)
```

The same thing goes for `interactiveDismissDisabled`, if you also want to control that. You can pass a `Bool` to it to indicate whether it is disabled.

For deeper navigation paths, it might be easier to use value-based navigation, so that you have access to a navigation path in `SheetA`, and can use the last element of the path to know what the navigation stack is currently showing, and determine what drag indicator visibility, detents, and interactive dismiss ability to use.